# Trouble formatting time subtractions in access while keeping data type

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Ok, I having been working on subtracting times in Access. It's a pain to say the least, however due to how the form is set up (someone set this up years before I started working at my job & it would be much too time consuming to fix), I cannot update a field in my table through an update query after a text box event is triggered on the form.

So I am however, able to do the calculations in VBA and place the values in the form's text box control to be updated into the table. I have searched online how to subtract the times and get the format displayed as I would like them to be...(hh:mm), however b doing this it converts the final product into a string and the table field linked to the text box is a number/double so I get a VBA error: "The value you entered isn't valid for this field"

Which I know is because it's now a string. I need help with getting the conversion the way I need it, and preserving a double type. CDbl(variable) is not working.

code:

```
    apptTime = DLookup("[Appt Time]", "T_PKMS", "[Load] = """ & loadNum & """")
    ArrvlTime = DLookup("[Arrival Time]", "T_PKMS", "[Load] = """ & loadNum & """")

    hoursPassedSinceAppt = ([Forms]![F_DriverLog].[Time Out].Value - apptTime)
    hoursPassedSinceArrvl = ([Forms]![F_DriverLog].[Time Out].Value - ArrvlTime)

    Me.Text51.Value = Format(hoursPassedSinceAppt, "hh:nn")
    Me.Text53.Value = Format(hoursPassedSinceArrvl, "hh:nn")
```

I have also tried:

```
    Debug.Print CDbl(Format(hoursPassedSinceAppt, "hh:nn"))
    Debug.Print CDbl(Format(hoursPassedSinceArrvl, "hh:nn"))
```

but I get a type mismatch error. Help I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: Is your textbox bound or unbound?  Is it actually storing the value as a time value or as a string?

Comment: its bound to a double type field in my table. so the text box needs the type as double but the VBA code is converting it to a string.

Comment: what datatypes are hoursPassedSinceAppt and hoursPassedSinceArrvl?  It looks like you are converting it from double to string and back.

Comment: they are both doubles. & youre right I converted them to a string to get the format i needed (hh:mm), instead of some 18 digit decimal number. but because they are doubles when was trying to place that variable back into my textbox to be saved in my table, the textbox rejected it because it was a string. So I needed to change it back to a double type in the hh:mm format. I seemed to have figured it out see below.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I have been staring at my code too long. I removed the "hh:nn" and changed the colon to a decimal and it allowed for cDbl() to change it from a string to a number.

I change:

```
Me.Text51.Value = Format(hoursPassedSinceAppt, "hh:nn")
```

To:

```
Me.Text51.Value = CDbl(Format(hoursPassedSinceAppt, "hh.nn"))
```

Comment: That won't work - 5 hours 59 minutes is not 5.59 hours.

Comment: May I suggest not using the format at all?  Since they are already of the data type Double you don't need to reformat them.  If you are looking to strip the date so that the variable only stores the time you could do.

Me.Text51.Value =  hoursPassedSinceAppt - INT(hoursPassedSinceAppt)

Comment: @YowE3K I understand what you both are trying to say, that 5hrs and 59 minutes is not equal to 5.59, however that is the format that my employer requested. I agree that it isn't the best way to display elapsed time but I am just providing what is requested.

Comment: But if the "table field linked to the text box is a number/double" then having `5.59` placed into the table is going to throw off all downstream calculations which will be treating that as 5 hours 35.4 minutes.  Make sure your employer knows that that is what is going to happen.